# Cocoa Hyperlink label issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a hyperlink label in my application.Clicking on it opens the application i want. 
The problem is after i click on it the font size of the label shrinks automatically. 
Is there a way to avoid this??
Please suggest a solution for this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code sample, on how the click is handled?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `UIButton` with `UIButtonTypeCustom` and clear background instead of `UILabel`. It will look like UILabel and in the action method you can perform any task.

```
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btn_frame];
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(DoSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTitle: @"Button_Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor: #your_choice forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor: #your_choice forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        btn.titleLabel.font = #your_choice
        btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = #your_choice;
        btn.contentVerticalAlignment = #your_choice;
```

if still you want UILabel here is link might help you..
[Attributed Label](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ohattributedlabel)